# Keras Model Accuracy starts from 0.667 and goes to 1.0

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I am trying to learn Keras and NN and tried to build a simple Neural Network.

My code is:

```
x = np.array([[0, 0, 1],
              [0, 1, 1],
              [1, 0, 1],
              [1, 1, 1]])

y = np.array([[0],
              [1],
              [1],
              [0]])

sc = StandardScaler()
x = sc.fit_transform(x)

y = to_categorical(y)

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size = 0.1)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
opt = SGD(lr=0.01)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=10000)
```

When i ran it it gives output like this:

```
Epoch 1/100
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step - loss: 0.6693 - accuracy: 0.6667
Epoch 2/100
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 505us/step - loss: 0.6688 - accuracy: 0.6667
.
.
Epoch 60/100
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 576us/step - loss: 0.6375 - accuracy: 1.0000
.
.
Epoch 100/100
3/3 [==============================] - 0s 717us/step - loss: 0.6181 - accuracy: 1.0000
```

The output seemed weird to me, did i make a mistake at implementation or is it normal for a simple input like this?

Comment: If the output is binary there is no point in putting it to categorical : use only one output neuron, and binary crossentropy.
The categorical_crossentropy should be used for more than two classes, and with a softmax activation on the last layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal - you have 3 examples that you're feeding to the network which are all unique for training and the jump in accuracy is your network being able to now classify 3/3 examples instead of 2/3 (which may have been random guesses at first).

Try lowering the batch_size to 1 or increasing your training set size to see the difference in how quickly it converges. Make sure to evaluate it on your test set as well.